# polymorphic association with separate forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, polymorphism

I have one model, `User`, and then 2 other models: `Editor` and `Administrator` associated with the user model via a polymorphic association, so I want to have 2 type of users, and they will have different fields, but I need them to share certain features (like sending messages between both).

I thus need to keep the user ids in one table, `users`, and the other data in other tables, but I want that when a user signs up they first create the account and then the profile according to the type of profile they did pick.

**model/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :profilable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

**model/administrator.rb**

```
class Administrator < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :user, :as => :profilable
end
```

**model/Editor.rb**

```
class Editor < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessor :iduser
has_one :user, :as => :profilable
end
```

**controllers/user.rb**

```
def create
@user = User.new(params[:user])

respond_to do |format|


  if @user.save
    if params[:tipo] == "editor"
     format.html {redirect_to new_editor_path(:iduser => @user.id)}
   else
     format.html { redirect_to new_administrator_path(@user) }
    end
  #  format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

**controllers/editor.rb**

```
def new

 @editor = Editor.new
 @editor.iduser = params[:iduser]
 respond_to do |format|
   format.html # new.html.erb
   format.json { render json: @editor }
  end
end

def create
 id = params[:iduser]
 @user = User.find(id)
 @editor = Editor.new(params[:editor])
 @editor.user = @user
 respond_to do |format|
  if @editor.save
   format.html { redirect_to @editor, notice: 'Editor was successfully created.' }
   format.json { render json: @editor, status: :created, location: @editor }
  else
   format.html { render action: "new" }
   format.json { render json: @editor.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

**views/editor/_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="field">
 <%= f.label :bio %><br />
 <%= f.text_area :bio %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :iduser%>
</div>
```

**routes.rb**

```
Orbit::Application.routes.draw do
 resources :administrators
 resources :editors
 resources :users
```

When someone creates a new user they have to pic "Editor" or "Administrator" with a radio button, then using that parameter, the code will create an Editor or Administrator profile.

I am not sure if i have the association right, because it should be "User has a profile (editor/administrator)" but in this case is "Profile (administrator/editor) has a user".

**The question:**

- Is the association right for what I want to accomplish?
- How could I pass the user to the new editor method?

The way i have it right now is not working, and as I said, the association doesn't seem to be right.

Thanks for the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and swap the association,
    The user will have an administrator profile, and administrator profile will belong_to the user.

```
Administrator(:user_id, :other_attributes)
Editor(:user_id, :other_attributes)
```

So that,

```
class Administrator < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
end

class Editor < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :administrator
 has_one :editor
end
```

Comment: Thank you, I gonna try it as soon as I can, but just to be sure, `Administrator(:user_id, :other_attributes)`, what that line does exactly? i guess I have to put it in the controller, but not sure, can you explain me a lil bit more about that block of code?

Comment: By other_attributes, I meant the remaining attributes that your administrator model will have. I just showed you the model attribute. Sorry, should have been more clear.

Comment: first than anyhthing Thank you for your time, i apreciate the help.  I see it now, well I had to ask cuz when is about rails some times some methods just are called exactly what they do, certainly my actual association is not how should be, I found a way to pass the param that I needed, using:  `format.html {redirect_to new_editor_path(:iduser => @user.id)}` and using `attr_accessor :iduser` on the Editor model, so far I did not change the assosiation cuz i want to fix the passing params thing first, cuz i just have it half way. dont like to let things half done, is a matter of pride i guess.